# Finding which OS a software requires?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, dependencies, windows-98

How to find a (ie., Portable single executable) software requires a particular OS (Win98, Win98SE, WinME, Win2000, WinXP, Linux).  I am using Win98SE in one pc and WinXP in another PC.  If I copy/install a portable software or package in win98se, only after installing / executing that software, that program tell us it requires WinXP,.  Is any software to find a particular software needs to run only in win98SE or greater.  I tried Dependency Walker by Steve Miller but no results.  Kindly help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly flags in the headers of the executable to indicate some sorts of compatibility, but I suspect it's only linked to 32- or 64-bits, and platform (MIPS, Alpha, PowerPC, Intel, ...) for older (NT3, NT4 times) executables.

Normally it's the role if the installer (if any) to check the OS compatibility. If there is no installer, the executable will do its OS compatibility check in the logic of the code itself, not in a known place you could check before running the application.

So, I doubt it, it depends where in the code and how the check is done and it changes for each application that does such a check.

Answer (score 2):

Look on the website or company that made it and see what they say is the minimum specification?

Answer (score 0):

I expect reply like that the software that analyses the executable and reports under which is OS, the executable runs.  Say, the following programs are analysed the executables but it does not give the result like the minimum OS required to run -

Dependancy Walker, Depends